# exception '-[nsnull absolutestring] was thrown while invoking getinitialurl on target linkingmanager

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-linking

Full error thrown:

```
[fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.linkingmanagerqueue] 
exception '-[nsnull absolutestring]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10d8b5ea8' 
was thrown while invoking getinitialurl on target linkingmanager with params (
626, 627
)
```

I am stuck, and have no idea what this error means and how to solve it.

I have ejected to ExpoKit, and am trying to add `react-native-fbsdk` to my project.

I have followed the instructions laid out here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk, and the android build went just fine.

After following the instructions for `ios` (except that I did `pod install`), and this error appeared.

I really would appreciate any help, thank you!